# Is the CLUI and GUI different TTYs?

Tags: command-line, tty, gui

Is the CLUI <sub>(Command Line User Interface)</sub> and GUI <sub>(Graphical User Interface)</sub> utilize different TTYs or both of them share the same TTY?

I understood in the past that they both share the same TTY but I might be wrong. I got a bit confused when reading about that and saw different phrasings that made see the CLUI/GUI-TTY issue a bit confusing one.

I understand what is a TTY machine from history (60s/70s) but don't know if a modern **virtual TTY** "bases" both CLUI and GUI, or if there is TTY one per each (one for CLUI and one for GUI), and my question is if there really is.

### Update due to Sparhawk's comment:

By **CLI** I mean to **either** the CLUI I run from my GUI-including-distro (like the Debian desktop CLUI) **or** my other no-GUI distro, like the Debian server CLUI or Ubuntu WSL.

Comment: It depends what you mean by a "CLI". Is that a terminal emulator that you run within your desktop environment? Or one that you run on… uh… a different tty? There's also some reading [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) that might clear up some of your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- CLUI: command line user interface
- GUI: graphic user interface

These things mean what they mean, no more.

These definitions don't include anything about a tty. For example, the cmd.exe on windows is also a CLUI, although it doesn't use any tty device (it is conceptionally nonexisting on Windows).

Tty means a virtual teletype console writer, which is the traditional name of the pseudo virtual terminals on the Unixes. By default (after boot), a character console runs on them, but you can connect anything to them.

The best thing to understand the ttys, if you think on them as *network sockets*: Processes can *listen* on them, and also *connect* them. In addition, there are various kernel APIs for the user interaction: for example, if a virtual terminal closes unexpectedly, changes its size, activates or deactivates, then the processes attached to them, get different *signals*. It is up to them, what they do with it.

For example, an X server running on tty7, if you switch to character console (alt/ctrl/f1), then it deinitializes the video card and switches back to character mode. Other processes, for example, a command shell, can totally different things.

Comment: Readers, if it's still isn't clear see [this other good answer by pereth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404388/258010).