# Is TTY only a metaphor in modern day Linux systems?

Tags: tty

Is the term TTY only a metaphor in modern day Linux systems referring to any CLI environment (direct as in GUI-less distros, and/or indirect as a CLI window in GUI-based distros).

Comment: The accepted solution gives a description of what a tty is which I think answers your question. Also, I didn't down-vote you and I don't think this question deserved to be down-voted.

Comment: This is a worthy question.  I found these terms *extremely* confusing when I first bumped into them; they're not at all easy to disentangle.  However, I agree with @igal; this question *is* reasonably well addressed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/135943.

Comment: A command-line interface does not necessary need a terminal or a terminal emulator. On a terminal or terminal emulator you can run not only command-line applications but also character cell applications (also known as full-screen applications), such as `aptitude` or the text editors `vim` or `nano`.

Comment: @AlexP , I think I get what you are saying (using `nano` doesn't require a `tty` device) but working with the 3 standard stream might require so (and I emphasize the "might"). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Using `nano` absolutely requires a tty; the point is that `nano` **is not a CLI application**; it's a character-cell application. Character-cell applications (such as `nano` or `vim` or `aptitude` or `mc` or `lynx`) by their very nature need a tty, because they need to have a bidimensional array of cells where to place the characters. A command-line application, such as `ls` or `bc` or `find` works fine without a tty. The three standard streams have nothing to do with terminals.

Comment: Nothing necessarily*, I assume you meant. Anyway, Alex, thanks for clarifying the difference between **CLI apps** and **Character-cell apps**. This is an important distinction I'll internalize well.

Comment: I don't see why the duplicate's answer doesn't address this. It clearly explains that a tty is a type of device file. I know it's a lot of information, but it should answer all your questions if you read through it carefully.

Comment: I never said it doesn't answer the question as well...

Comment: Then I don't see any reason to reopen. Your question has been answered and anyone else with the same question will be redirected to that very comprehensive answer and have their question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a metaphor in the sense that the name is coming from the [TeleType console writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33):

[image]

...which was essentially an ancient electromechanical writing machine. It was used as the keyboard of some ancient unix big computer.

Today, the few remaining parts of them are in IT museums. But the [console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_console) [character devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) still named as `/dev/tty` or similarly.

Its current meaning is roughly "kernel-driven character console".

Many character environments *don't need* a tty device for a functioning CLUI (Command Line User Interface), and may work with or without one.